# Matplotlib basemap polygon throws an error but succeeds if something is plotted

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, patch, matplotlib-basemap

I've been using basemap with matplotlib in python for quite a while now but was building up a new piece of code and came across this really strange anomaly and I don't know how to get round it.

If I have a polygon that I want to plot in matplotlib using (lonList,latList) the show command will throw an error when plotting the polygon with an allocation error. Or on another machine I've seen that it will plot a blank screen.

However if I use the same list and add a scatter plot (commented line below) it will work. Also if I plot a line or scatter plot on its own it will work, but plotting the polygon patch on its own fails. I have no clue why this is and cannot find any bug report on it. Please help?

By the way I'm running Debian Jessie 8 with python 2.7 if that helps.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.collections    import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches        import Polygon

def singlePatchExample():
  patches = []
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(19.2,10.8))
  ax  = plt.subplot(111)

  lonSW = -8.0
  latSW = 51.0
  lonNE = -6.0
  latNE = 53.0
  centLon = ( lonSW + lonNE ) / 2.0
  centLat = ( latSW + latNE ) / 2.0

  baseMap = Basemap(llcrnrlon=lonSW,llcrnrlat=latSW,urcrnrlon=lonNE,urcrnrlat=latNE,\
                resolution='i', lat_0 = centLon, lon_0 = centLat)

  longList = [ -7.0, -7.5, -7.7 ]
  latList  = [ 51.5, 52.0, 52.5 ]

  x, y    = baseMap( longList, latList )
  polygon = Polygon(zip(x,y), True )
  patches.append(polygon)

  patchInSingleImage = PatchCollection(patches, alpha=0.2)
  ax.add_collection(patchInSingleImage)
  ax.set_title("Single Patch Example, (without points????)")

  #baseMap.scatter( x, y, color='r' )

  plt.show()

singlePatchExample()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running the code I get a figure with axes but no polygon being shown. This should actually be the same with and without basemap. The reason is that matplotlib does not autoscale when the only artist inside an axes is a PatchCollection (or probably just any collection).

The solution in such cases would be to add

```
ax.autoscale()
```

after adding the collection.

The main point is that since there isn't actually anything on the map, the scaling needs to be taken over by the matplotlib axes. You can make sure the map is actually being connected to the axes by drawing something unneeded with zero linewidth to the map.

```
baseMap.drawrivers(linewidth=0)
```

This would make `ax.autoscale()` superfluous and will scale the map just as if it had a some data on it. Equally, drawing parallels or meridians would have the same effect - just anything that would actually draw the map to the axes.

```
baseMap.drawparallels(latList)
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but how do I retain the original SW,NE boundary. This is also important to preserve. I still think its worth a +1 to you since I couldn't even guess this. It still looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Well, as long as you don't have anthing on the map, there is no map being shown. Just make sure to have the map in the axes. I updated the answer with some possible options.